# sorting mixed string numerically PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How Can I sort following files numerically, I mean   1 2 3 4...

**I have used `sort()`, `asort()`, `sort(, sort_numeric)` functions but it is not working**

> 4 Walka Duchowa Madry Umysl Zamkniety Na Sily Demoniczne.mp3
>   3 Walka Duchowa Swieci Na Terytorium wroga.mp3
>   21 Walka Duch Oszczep Modlitwy _08_12_12.mp3
>   20 Walka Duchowa  Oszczep.mp3
>   5 Walka Duchowa Chrzescijanstwo Ciezko Zbrojna Artyleria.mp3
>   6 Walka Duchowa W Koncu Bracia Moi.mp3
>   9 Walka Duchowa Pas Prawdy.mp3
>   8 Walka Duchowa Diabelskie Zasadzki.mp3
>   7 Walka Duchowa.mp3
>   2 Walka Duchowa Rozbrojony Wrog.mp3
>   19 Walka Duchowa Oszczep_cz_C.mp3
>   13 Walka_duchowa Helm Zbawiebia 06_17_12.mp3
>   12 Walka_duchowa Tarcza Wiary__06_10_12.mp3
>   11 Walka Duchowa Obuwie Pokoju.mp3
>   10 Walka Duchowa Pancerz Sprawiedliosci.mp3
>   13b Walka Duchowa Helm Zbawienia 06_24_12.mp3
>   15 Walka Duchowa Miecz Ducha 07-01-12.mp3
>   18 Walka Duch Oszczep Modlitwy _07_22_12.mp3
>   17 Walka_Duch Oszczep Modlitwy 07_15_12.mp3
>   16 Walka Duch  16 Miecz Ducha 07_08_12.mp3
>   1 Walka Duchowa Niweczenie mocy diabla.mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`natsort()`](http://php.net/natsort) will give the order that you are looking for, even with files like `13` and `13b`.

The question is a little devious, since you don't really want to sort solely *numerically*.

---

```
<?php

$files = explode("\n", trim('
7 Walka Duchowa.mp3
2 Walka Duchowa Rozbrojony Wrog.mp3
13 Walka_duchowa Helm Zbawiebia 06_17_12.mp3
12 Walka_duchowa Tarcza Wiary__06_10_12.mp3
13b Walka Duchowa Helm Zbawienia 06_24_12.mp3
15 Walka Duchowa Miecz Ducha 07-01-12.mp3
'));

natsort($files);
echo implode("\n", $files);
```

Gives the following order:

```
2 Walka Duchowa Rozbrojony Wrog.mp3
7 Walka Duchowa.mp3
12 Walka_duchowa Tarcza Wiary__06_10_12.mp3
13 Walka_duchowa Helm Zbawiebia 06_17_12.mp3
13b Walka Duchowa Helm Zbawienia 06_24_12.mp3
15 Walka Duchowa Miecz Ducha 07-01-12.mp3
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all your files are starting with a number you can try this:

```
$files = array(
    '4 Walka.mp3',
    '3 Walka.mp3',
    '21 Walka.mp3',
    '5 Walka.mp3'
); // shortened but you get the idea

function mysort($a, $b)
{
    return intval($a) - intval($b);
}

usort($files, 'mysort');

print_r($files);
```

[usort](http://php.net/usort)

The best answer to this question has been posted by salathe, see his answer

Comment: In addition, if the intvals are the same, you can do a string comparison as a secondary check, so that `1 foo` always comes after `1 bar`.

Comment: Nice idea yes (that is all)

Answer (score 0):

Use usort:

```
function byFirstNumWord($a, $b) {
    $pa = explode(' ',$a);
    $pb = explode(' ',$b);
    if ($pa[0] == $pb[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($pa[0] < $pb[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'byFirstNumWord');
print_t($array);
```